# Architecture for a Customer/Project/Quote/Order system

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design, architectural-patterns

I am working on figuring out the architecture for putting together a complex modular system that has Orders, Customers, Projects and Quotes.

The customer can have multiple projects. For each project there will be at least one order or quote associated but there is the possibility of having multiple quotes and orders on each project that belongs to a customer. In the software requirements it should not be possible to have a Quote or Order without it being tied to a project.

The hang-up I am having is figuring out how to create the classes around this system. It feels wrong to have a `Customer` class that has `Projects`, `Orders`, and `Quotes` properties which contain all of the items. It seems like the `Customers` class should be extended some how to add these items rather than hard-coded as properties. Is there a design pattern I could be using, such as the decorator pattern?

Comment: You don’t need a design pattern. But you should definitely learn about Aggregation and Composition as they pertain to object oriented design.  Inheritance isn’t needed here.

Comment: What do you mean with `Quotes`. Like comments?

Comment: @AK_is_curious no. `Quotes` are what a customer would be sent to review that has line items, prices, etc. on it. When that customer purchases the `Quote` then an `Order` is created.

Comment: It's far too early to think about design patterns. You need to design an abstract model  based on use cases first. Think about the entities and their relations first. Design a DB (or class) model. Validate your use cases against it. See where it fails. Iteratively refactor until you are confident your cover all these pesky cases, like when a customer orders something that isn't related to an actual project  (should you use a dummy project? Sub-project? Etc.) Think about persistence, deployment constraints, user rights and roles, development budget, etc. Patterns won't help you at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly inheritance or inheritance based design patterns are not required for your current requirement. We can create the classes `Customer`, `Project`, `Order` and `Quote` right away. We need to carefully identify the relations between them so that we can decide about placing properties and methods.

You mentioned that `Customer` can have multiple `Project`s. So `Customer` class will have `Lis<Project>` and an `addProject(Project)` method.

```
    public class Customer {
        private List<Project> projects;

        public void addProject(Project project) {
            projects.add(project);
        }
    }
```

In the same way `Project` should contain a `List<Quote>` and `List<Order>` to store quotes and orders. But the `add***()` methods have to be designed little trickier.

Lets see about `Quote` and `Order`. Your software requirement says that `Quote` or `Order` can not exist without being tied to a `Project`. So you need a constructor in `Quote` and `Order` which accepts a `Project` instance. A few things are worthy to note here.

1. We need to add the `Quote` or `Order` to the `Project` class. The right place to do this is the constructor of `Quote` or `Order`.

   ```
   public class Quote {
       private Project project;

       public Quote(Project project) {
           project = p;
           project.addQuote(this);
       }
   }

   public class Order {
       private Project project;

       public Order(Project project) {
           project = p;
           project.addOrder(this);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Often the right place to write these classes is inside the `Project` class (static inner classes). You can see this pattern in `Menu` and `MenuItems`, `Tab` and `TabItems`, etc. where `MenuItems` and `TabItems` can not exist without being tied to `Menu` or `Tab`. One more example is `Iterator` and `List`.
3. Their constructors are made inaccessible by making them private and the `add***()` will become factory methods in the enclosing class which returns the instance.

   ```
   public class Project {
       private List<Quote> quotes;
       private List<Order> orders;

       public Quote addQuote(int id) {
           Quote quote = new Quote(this, id);
           quotes.add(quote);
           return quote;
       }

       public Order addOrder(int id) {
           Order order = new Order(this, id);
           orders.add(order);
           return order;
       }

       public static class Quote {
           private final int id;
           private final Project project;

           private Quote(Project project, int id) {
               project = p;
               this.id = id;
           }
       }

       public static class Order {
           private final int id;
           private final Project project;

           private Order(Project project, int id) {
               project = p;
               this.id = id;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The params of `addQuote()` and `addOrder()` could be changed according to the need.

Now the last problem to address is there should be at least one `Quote` or `order` in a `Project`. We can solve this by having static factory methods in `Project`.

```
    public class Project {
        // Fields

        private Project() {
            // Initialise the fields
        }

        public static Project createWithQuote(int id) {
            Project p = new Project();
            p.addQuote(id);
            return p;
        }

        public static Project createWithQuotes(int[] ids) {
            Project p = new Project();
            for (int id : ids)
                p.addQuote(id);
            return p;
        }

        // Add similar static factories for Order

        // Rest of the code

    }
```

The private constructor and static factories improve readability and avoid constructor overloading clashes. If you wish you can use pubic overloaded constructors also. If the class is to be subclassed make the constructor protected.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like the Customers class should be extended some how to add these items [...]

Why? Extension/inheritance is used when you want to centralize common code between similar objects. This would be a great way to define multiple types of `Customers` where you could have one which has a name and surname for private customers while you could have another with a company name for businesses. Both share common properties and implementation in `Customer` but are their own respective classes in  `BusinessCustomer` and `PrivateCustomer`.

You could ask "What's the address of our customer Mr. Smith?" But would you really ask "What's the prize of our customer Mr. Smith?" - what prize? The cost of his project? Did he win a prize at a tournament? This is not a valid question because this property is not directly associated with the customer but with something else, which in turn could lead us to the customer.

So why would you want your customer to have a prize, a team leader, starting date, due date, banking information, ... ?
These are all properties you would have in your customer, yet they are not part of what makes a customer a customer, like name, address, date of birth, ...

That's the whole point of having separate classes.

> [...] rather than hard-coded as properties

Hard-coded properties? Those are variable variables with nice variable content. Those do not have to be hard-coded at all - they shouldn't be actually.

You are going to create and connect new objects at runtime via a form in your UI.

Here you answered your question on your own:

> [1] The **customer** can have *multiple* **projects**.
>
> [2] For each **project** there will be *at least one* **order** or **quote** associated [...]
>
> [3] In the software requirements it should not be possible to have a Quote or Order without it being tied to a project.

```
[1] Customer 1:n Projects
[2] Project 1:n Order
[2] Project 1:n Quote
[3] The constructor of your Order and Quote take a Project as parameter to which they will be bound.
```

So define a class Customer in which you have a list of projects. Define a class Project in which you have a list of Orders and a list of Quotes.

As stated before: Orders and Quotes take a Project for their constructor and add themselves to their list. Then you can create Customers and Projects and add the Projects to the Customers project-lists.

> Is there a design pattern I could be using, such as the decorator pattern?

Design patterns don't make your program automatically good and it is because of people like you, who instantly look for a predefined pattern to follow, that many people dislike them.

Besides that you really don't need some complicated pattern here. The bigger task will be to find out what values you want to save, what to do with them and how to create them in a meaningful UI.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are focusing on the relations between objects (data, mostly) with their cardinalities, this sounds a lot more like a relational database problem.

If you design a good database with your existing constraints, you can create code automatically from the database using modern IDEs

It might be very beneficial to look at the following link to understand an automatized approach to create plain old (java) objects from an existing database structure:

[Java EE 6 Hands-on Lab OTN Developer Day](https://cdn.app.compendium.com/uploads/user/e7c690e8-6ff9-102a-ac6d-e4aebca50425/f4a5b21d-66fa-4885-92bf-c4e81c06d916/File/e62228a6aadd27166fccc22819ec4a45/javaee6_hol_2012.pdf), using the [VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/javadev-vm-192138.html).